# "How to Edit" sidebar shows up in wrong, awkward place when improving a suggested edit from the "edit (1)" popup

Tags: feature-request, bug, review, suggested-edits, responsive-design

When improving a suggested edit from the Q&A page itself (as opposed to from the review queue), the sidebar widget is positioned awkwardly, both to the right and under the edit form:

[image]

It also seems to disappear entirely when you start editing the post. Since the space is limited, and users need to have 2,000 reputation for this action and are presumably aware of these rules, I think it's safe to not show the widget at all.

Comment: For extra fun, try improving an edit on a phone. (You have to use the full site view, suggested edits are invisible in the mobile view).